# Space between Column's children in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `Column` widget with two `TextField` widgets as children and I want to have some space between both of them.

I already tried `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround`, but the result was not what I wanted.

Comment: Simply Put SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
        ),
Between the two TextField

Comment: `margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 200.0, top: 300.0))`

Answer (score 338, accepted):

You can use `Padding` widget in between those two widget or wrap those widgets with `Padding` widget.

**Update**

**[SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html)** widget can be use in between two widget to add space between two widget and it makes code more readable than padding widget.

Ex:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Widget1(),
    SizedBox(height: 10),
    Widget2(),
  ],
),
```

Comment: I sure wish that `column`-class had that property included. It will be a waste of coding time for getting a padding between all children.

Comment: How can you wrap two widget in a Padding widget when padding widgets only take a single child parameter?

Comment: @ScottF the answer said that the `Padding` widget goes **in between** the 2 widgets. It's not that the 2 widgets becomes children of `Padding`.

Comment: It straight up says "or wrap those widgets with Padding widget"....

Comment: @ScottF Make the child a column or row with the two widgets as children.

Comment: You can have similar result just replacing what our colleague Viren did by:
`Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(yourDesiredPaddingValue))`.

Answer (score 177):

You can put a `SizedBox` with a specific `height` between the widgets, like so:

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    FirstWidget(),
    SizedBox(height: 100),
    SecondWidget(),
  ],
),
```

**Why to prefer this over wrapping the widgets in `Padding`?** Readability! There is less visual boilerplate, less indention and the code follows the typical reading-order.

Comment: Adding a sized box is like adding an empty view right ? would nt that lead to any problems ?

Comment: `SizedBox` is just a normal widget that has a desired size it tries to be during layout, but doesn't render anything. All the leaf widgets like Text or Container are empty too, so that's okay.

Answer (score 157):

There are many ways of doing it, I'm listing a few here.

1. Use **`SizedBox`** and provide some height:

   ```
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Widget1(),
        SizedBox(height: 10), // <-- Set height
        Widget2(),
      ],
    )
   ```
2. Use **`Spacer`**

   ```
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Widget1(),
        Spacer(), // <-- Spacer
        Widget2(),
      ],
    )
   ```
3. Use **`Expanded`**

   ```
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Widget1(),
        Expanded(child: SizedBox.shrink()), // <-- Expanded
        Widget2(),
      ],
    )
   ```
4. Set **`mainAxisAlignment`**

   ```
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, // <-- alignments
      children: <Widget>[
        Widget1(),
        Widget2(),
      ],
    )
   ```
5. Use **`Wrap`**

   ```
    Wrap(
      direction: Axis.vertical, 
      spacing: 20, // <-- Spacing between children
      children: <Widget>[
        Widget1(),
        Widget2(),
      ],
    )
   ```

Comment: This is SUPER helpful to know all the different ways to do. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Another one is to wrap `Widget2` inside a `Padding` with `padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)`.

Comment: I agree this answer is the most helpful.  Especially the Wrap showing direction in vertical axis.  Thanks!

Answer (score 151):

you can use `Wrap()` widget instead `Column()` to add space between child widgets.And use spacing property to give equal spacing between children

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 20, // to apply margin in the main axis of the wrap
  runSpacing: 20, // to apply margin in the cross axis of the wrap
  children: <Widget>[
     Text('child 1'),
     Text('child 2')
  ]
)
```

Comment: Use `runSpacing` instead of `spacing` for gaps in between vertically spaced items

Comment: This worked to me. I think it is the best solution at all but what would be the disavantages of using Wrap() instead of Column() ?

Comment: Column is an expanded widget while Wrap isn't. so when you want to expand the whole space of the parent, you should use expanded widgets like Column or Row, etc. This depends on your case

Comment: Yes, this is much better than wrapping each child individually.  Good suggestion.

Comment: which is better for Flutter Web?

Comment: This is perfect if you want to bring two widgets closer together. Just make the runSpacing a negative value.

Comment: This doesn't put it in a column layout, does it?

Comment: even `direction: Axis.horizontal` doesn't make it look like a column

Answer (score 38):

Just use padding to wrap it like this:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
  Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Text('Hello World!'),
  ),
  Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Text('Hello World2!'),
  )
]);
```

You can also use Container(padding...) or SizeBox(height: x.x). The last one is the most common but it will depents of how you want to manage the space of your widgets, I like to use padding if the space is part of the widget indeed and use sizebox for lists for example.

Comment: is there a way to do something like css grid-gap?

Answer (score 26):

I don't see this solution here, so just for the sake of completeness I'll post it.

You can also wrap children with `Padding` using `map`:

```dart
Column(
      children: [Text('child 1'), Text('child 2')]
          .map(
            (e) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: e,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
```

Comment: This is a better way than adding ```sizedBox()``` after each widget.

Comment: @abrsh it's useful sometimes, yet it doesn't really add the space **between** items, but around them.

Answer (score 17):

I also wish there was some built-in way in Flutter to do this. Like a parameter you could pass to Column or Row. Sometimes you don't want padding around every element but you want space between them. Especially if you have more than two children, it's kind of tedious to write something like

```
const double gap = 10;
return Column(
  children: [
    Text('Child 1'),
    SizedBox(height: gap),
    Text('Child 2'),
    SizedBox(height: gap),
    Text('Child 3'),
    SizedBox(height: gap),
    Text('Child 4'),
  ],
);
```

However, I've came up with one quick (not perfect) solution:

Add this somewhere in your project (only once):

```
extension ListSpaceBetweenExtension on List<Widget> {
  List<Widget> withSpaceBetween({double? width, double? height}) => [
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      ...[
        if (i > 0)
          SizedBox(width: width, height: height),
        this[i],
      ],
  ];
}
```

And from now on whenever you have a Row or a Column, you can write

```
Column(
  children: [
    Text('Child 1'),
    Text('Child 2'),
    Text('Child 3'),
    Text('Child 4'),
  ].withSpaceBetween(height: 10),
),
```

When using Row you'll have to replace 'height' with 'width'.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. Clear to read, concise, and doesn't leave leading or trailing spaces like the `map` based solutions.

Comment: I like this answer, but you can improve performance for larger lists by using adding the first element and then iterating from index 1 (instead of zero) `[if (isNotEmpty) this[0], for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) ...[SizedBox(width: width, height: height), this[i]]]`. This way element 0 is added and all remaining elements do not require an if check.

Comment: This extension is brilliant and should become the accepted answer. It is particularly valuable when you just want to pass a list of widgets to your column in the first place, because you don't have the option to add the `SizedBox`es manually in that case even if you wanted to.

Answer (score 9):

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    FirstWidget(),
    Spacer(),
    SecondWidget(),
  ]
)
```

Spacer creates a flexible space to insert into a [Flexible] widget. (Like a column)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to help others understand it better. Code only answers are considered impolite and it may not help the OP understand the problem that you are trying to help with.

Answer (score 7):

The same way SizedBox is used [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774921/space-between-columns-children-in-flutter/52800342#52800342) for the purpose of code readability, you can use the Padding widget in the same manner and not have to make it a parent widget to any of the Column's children

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    FirstWidget(),
    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0)),
    SecondWidget(),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't wanna wrap Padding with every widget or repeat SizedBox.

Try this:

```
Column(
        children: [
          Widget(),
          Widget(),
          Widget(),
          Widget(),
        ]
            .map((e) => Padding(
                  child: e,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
```

That will warp all the widgets with padding without repetition.

Comment: The answer needs supporting information for better understanding.

Comment: @pmadhu I've added more details

Answer (score 4):

Columns Has no height by default,
You can Wrap your Column to the Container and add the specific height to your Container.
Then You can use something like below:

```
Container(
   width: double.infinity,//Your desire Width
   height: height,//Your desire Height
   child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
         Text('One'),
         Text('Two')
      ],
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem in different way.

> If you use **Row/Column** then you have to use **mainAxisAlignment:
>   MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly**
>
> If you use ***Wrap*** Widget you have to use **runSpacing: 5, spacing:
>   10,**
>
> In anywhere you can use **SizeBox()**

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/70993832/14298786, use extension on `List<Widget>` to add the `SizedBox`:

```dart
extension on List<Widget> {
  List<Widget> insertBetweenAll(Widget widget) {
    var result = List<Widget>.empty(growable: true);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result.add(this[i]);
      if (i != length - 1) {
        result.add(widget);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Use like this:

```dart
Column(children: [
  Widget1(),
  Widget2(),
  Widget3(),
].insertBetweenAll(SizedBox(height: 20)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a helper function to add spacing after each child.

```dart
List<Widget> childrenWithSpacing({
  @required List<Widget> children,
  double spacing = 8,
}) {
  final space = Container(width: spacing, height: spacing);
  return children.expand((widget) => [widget, space]).toList();
}
```

So then, the returned list may be used as a children of a column

```dart
Column(
  children: childrenWithSpacing(
    spacing: 14,
    children: [
      Text('This becomes a text with an adjacent spacing'),
      if (true == true) Text('Also, makes it easy to add conditional widgets'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I'm not sure though if it's wrong or have a performance penalty to run the children through a helper function for the same goal?

Comment: What if I want to remove space between any two children widgets?

Answer (score 2):

Column widget doesn't have its own height, it just expanded as we added inside the children widget.
for if you need the same space  between multiple widgets so,

```
Container(
   width: double.infinity,
   height: height,
   child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
         Text('One'),
         Text('Two'),
         Text('Three'),
         Text('Four')
      ],
   ),
),
```

or just added custom space between them by using SizeBox, Spacer, or widget,
like this

```
Column(
   children: <Widget>[
         Text('One'),
         SizedBox(height: 20), 
         Text('Two'),
         SizedBox(height: 40), 
         Text('Three'),
         SizedBox(height: 30), 
         Text('Four')
   ],
 ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
   Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:12, child: yourWidget)),
   Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:12, child: yourWidget))
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding multiple sized boxes gets tedious if you have too many children in a column, row, listView, etc., and if you have to do the same thing in many places in your application.

You can use the following utils to encapsulate the logic of adding these sized boxes:

```
List<Widget> addHorizontalSpaceBetweenElements(double space, List<Widget> widgets) {
  return _addSpaceBetweenElements(widgets, () => SizedBox(width: space));
}

List<Widget> addVerticalSpaceBetweenElements(double space, List<Widget> widgets) {
  return _addSpaceBetweenElements(widgets, () => SizedBox(height: space));
}

List<Widget> _addSpaceBetweenElements(List<Widget> widgets, ValueGetter<SizedBox> sizedBoxGetter) {
  if (widgets.isEmpty || widgets.length == 1) {
    return widgets;
  }
  List<Widget> spacedWidgets = [widgets.first];
  for (var i = 1; i < widgets.length - 1; i++) {
    spacedWidgets.add(sizedBoxGetter());
    spacedWidgets.add(widgets[i]);
  }
  spacedWidgets.add(sizedBoxGetter());
  spacedWidgets.add(widgets.last);
  return spacedWidgets;
}
```

And you use them like this:

```
Column(
  children: addVerticalSpaceBetweenElements(5, [
    Text(),
    Text(),
  Row(children: addHorizontalSpaceBetweenElements(5, [
    Text(),
    Text(),
  ])),
  ]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**// provide fixed space defined in sizedbox**


 Column(
     children: [
          widget1(),
          sizedbox(height:20), 
          widget2()
        ] 
     )

**// Provides equal space between childs** 

Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [
     widget1(),
     widget2()
   ] 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative I'm surprised isn't listed here is to simply use `ListView.separated`. I use this quite a lot for lists, often using `const Divider()` as a material-style separator line for the spacer.

```
List<Widget> yourListOfWidgets = [
  const Text("Foo"),
  const Text("Bar"),
];
    
return ListView.separated(
  itemCount: yourListOfWidgets.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => yourListOfWidgets[index],
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(height: 10),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically all of the above answers are totally fine for small pieces of UI but if you are looking for a reusable and clean way to place a separator widget inside of a column, this might be what you are looking for:

```
class SeparatedColumn extends Column {
  SeparatedColumn({
    Key? key,
    MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,
    MainAxisSize mainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.max,
    CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    VerticalDirection verticalDirection = VerticalDirection.down,
    TextBaseline? textBaseline,
    Widget? separator,
    required List<Widget> children,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          children: List.generate(
            children.length * 2 - 1,
            (index) => index % 2 == 0
                ? children[index ~/ 2]
                : separator ?? const SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
          mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
          mainAxisSize: mainAxisSize,
          crossAxisAlignment: crossAxisAlignment,
          textDirection: textDirection,
          verticalDirection: verticalDirection,
          textBaseline: textBaseline,
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter `extension` can be beneficial here, and if we've too many children and want to add some padding between children, we can create an `extension` on `Column`. Here is an example

```
extension ColumnExtension on Column {
  Column childrenPadding(EdgeInsets padding) {
    return Column(
      children: children.map((e) => e.padding(padding)).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Usage

```
class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(AppStrings.settings)),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SettingTile(
              title: AppStrings.darkMode,
              leading: Icon(LineIcons.sun, color: context.primary),
            ),
            SettingTile(
              title: AppStrings.language,
              leading: Icon(LineIcons.language, color: context.primary),
            ),
            SettingTile(
              title: AppStrings.language,
              leading: Icon(LineIcons.language, color: context.primary),
            ),
            SettingTile(
              title: AppStrings.language,
              leading: Icon(LineIcons.language, color: context.primary),
            ),
          ],
        ).childrenPadding(const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result

[image: Column Extension example]

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use SizedBox() widget between your column's children.
Hope that'll be usefull

Answer (score 0):

Extract the input field widgets into a custom widget that is wrapped in padding or a container with padding (assuming symmetrical spacing).

Having sized boxes in-between every column child (as suggested in other answers) is not practical or maintainable. If you wanted to change the spacing you would have to change each sized box widget.

```
// An input field widget as an example column child
class MyCustomInputWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomInputWidget({Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // wrapping text field in container
    return Container(
      // here is the padding :)
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: TextField(...)
    );
  }
}
```

*...then the column in the parent class*

```
column(
  children: <Widget>[
    MyCustomInputWidget(),
    SizedBox(height: 10),
    MyCustomInputWidget(),
  ],
),
```

Obviously you would want the custom widget to have some sort of constructor to handle different field parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A package called [spaces2](https://pub.dev/packages/spaces2) can be used for this purpose.

By the way below, you can easily implement spaces between objects in columns or rows.

```swift
// Without Gap
Column(children: [x,y,z]);
// With Gaps Added
SpacedColumn(spaceBetween: 10, children: [x,y,z]);
```

Answer (score -1):

The sized box will not help in the case, the phone is in landscape mode.

```
body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
           child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFF1D1E33),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
           child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFF1D1E33),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
           child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFF1D1E33),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
     )
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another option involving a for loop.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    for (var i = 0; i < widgets.length; i++)
      Column(
        children: [
          widgets[i], // The widget you want to create or place goes here.
          SizedBox(height: 10) // Any kind of padding or other widgets you want to put.
        ])
  ],
),
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomColumn extends Column {
  CustomColumn({
    Key? key,
    MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,
    MainAxisSize mainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.max,
    CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    VerticalDirection verticalDirection = VerticalDirection.down,
    TextBaseline? textBaseline,
    List children = const [],
    EdgeInsetsGeometry? rowPadding,
  }) : super(
          children: children.map((e) => Padding(padding : rowPadding ?? EdgeInsets.only(bottom:12), child : e)).toList(),
          key: key,
          mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
          mainAxisSize: mainAxisSize,
          crossAxisAlignment: crossAxisAlignment,
          textDirection: textDirection,
          verticalDirection: verticalDirection,
          textBaseline: textBaseline,
        );
}
```

and call

```
CustomColumn(children: [
                    item1,
                    item2,
                    item3,
                  ])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Padding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) to wrap each child widget, and then set the `top` or `bottom` of Padding.

If you don’t want to write a lot of the same numbers, you can do it like this:

```
Column(
  children: [
    child1, 
    child2, 
    ..., 
    childN
  ].map((e) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10), child: e)).toList()
);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's best to use the Wrap widget instead of a column or row.

Wrap(
spacing: 10,
runSpacing: 10,
children:[],
)

Comment: This does not directly answer the poster's question. There are different opinions on what is the best.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).