# Set the space between Elements in Row Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Code:

```
new Container(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text('Don\'t have an account?', style: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF2E3233))),
              ),
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text('Register.', style: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF84A2AF), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                onPressed: moveToRegister,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

And here is the result: https://dartpad.dev/?id=6bbfc6139bdf32aa7b47eebcdf9623ba

How to fix that the two `FlatButton` elements are side by side without space between the center of the screen width?

Comment: check, [Flutter — Row/Column Cheat Sheet](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041)

Comment: Did u try: `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround`?

Comment: Add sizedbox. Check this https://mightytechno.com/flutter-row-widget/

Comment: just add a sizedbox if you want a fixed amount of space.

Comment: solution using package `spaces2`: [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78008120/15439845)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Removing Space-:

```
new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                child: new Text('Don\'t have an account?',
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF2E3233))),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){},
                  child: new Text(
                'Register.',
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF84A2AF), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ))
            ],
          ),
```

OR

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){},
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('Don\'t have an account?',
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF2E3233))),
                new Text(
                  'Register.',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFF84A2AF), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. With `GestureDetector` everything works great.

Comment: One downside of using `GestureDetector`, you have to manage ripple effect (button feedback) on your own and without having this, you end up having a weird UX

Comment: Replace "GestureDetector" with "InkWell" and you will get back at least some kind of ripple effect.

Answer (score 402):

There are many ways of doing it, I'm listing a few here:

1. Use **`SizedBox`** if you want to set some specific space

   ```
   Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Text("1"),
       SizedBox(width: 50), // give it width
       Text("2"),
     ],
   )
   ```

   [image]

---

2. Use **`Spacer`** if you want both to be as far apart as possible.

   ```
   Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Text("1"),
       Spacer(), // use Spacer
       Text("2"),
     ],
   )
   ```

   [image]

---

3. Use **`mainAxisAlignment`** according to your needs:

   ```
   Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, // use whichever suits your need
     children: <Widget>[
       Text("1"),
       Text("2"),
     ],
   )
   ```

   [image]

---

4. Use **`Wrap` instead of `Row`** and give some **`spacing`**

   ```
   Wrap(
     spacing: 100, // set spacing here
     children: <Widget>[
       Text("1"),
       Text("2"),
     ],
   )
   ```

   [image]

---

5. Use **`Wrap` instead of `Row`** and give it **alignment**

   ```
   Wrap(
     alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceAround, // set your alignment
     children: <Widget>[
       Text("1"),
       Text("2"),
     ],
   )
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Missing flex :)

Comment: I think `Flex` isn't necessary as per Flutter docs: `If you know the main axis in advance, then consider using a Row (if it's horizontal) or Column (if it's vertical) instead, because that will be less verbose`

Comment: use what, if I want both to be as close as possible.

Answer (score 205):

***MainAxisAlignment***

**start** - Place the children as close to the start of the main axis as possible.

[image]

**end** - Place the children as close to the end of the main axis as possible.

[image]

**center** - Place the children as close to the middle of the main axis as possible.

[image]

**spaceBetween** - Place the free space evenly between the children.

[image]

**spaceAround** - Place the free space evenly between the children as well as half of that space before and after the first and last child.

[image]

**spaceEvenly** - Place the free space evenly between the children as well as before and after the first and last child.

[image]

*Example:*

```
  child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Row1'),
          Text('Row2')
        ],
      )
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where both of my text are of different length, so when I place them in center close to each other, together they seem off-center.

Answer (score 25):

You can use Spacers if all you want is a little bit of spacing between items in a row. The example below centers 2 Text widgets within a row with some spacing between them.

Spacer creates an adjustable, empty spacer that can be used to tune the spacing between widgets in a `Flex` container, like `Row` or `Column`.

In a `row`, if we want to put space between two widgets such that it occupies all remaining space.

```
    widget = Row (
    children: <Widget>[
      Spacer(flex: 20),
      Text(
        "Item #1",
      ),
      Spacer(),  // Defaults to flex: 1
      Text(
        "Item #2",
      ),
      Spacer(flex: 20),
    ]
  );
```

Answer (score 6):

To make an exact spacing, I use `Padding`. An example with two images:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Image.asset('images/user1.png'),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Image.asset('images/user2.png'),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Row(
 children: <Widget>[
  Flexible(
   child: TextFormField()),
  Container(width: 20, height: 20),
  Flexible(
   child: TextFormField())
 ])
```

This works for me, there are 3 widgets inside row: Flexible, Container, Flexible

Comment: Since you are going down this road, why not just use SizedBox(width: 10)....

Answer (score 5):

Just add "Container(width: 5, color: Colors.transparent)," between elements

```
new Container(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text('Don\'t have an account?', style: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF2E3233))),
          ),
            Container(width: 5, color: Colors.transparent),
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text('Register.', style: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF84A2AF), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            onPressed: moveToRegister,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the original post was about *removing* the space between the buttons in a row, not adding space.

The trick is that the minimum space between the buttons was due to padding built into the buttons as part of the material design specification.

So, don't use buttons! But a GestureDetector instead. This widget type give the `onClick` / `onTap` functionality but without the styling.

See this post for an example.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56001817/766115

Comment: Thank you I cant believe they don't even have a padding property. I spent almost half an hour trying to figure out this imaginary space!!!

Answer (score 2):

With a column `extension`, use like:

```
Column.withSpacing(
  spacing: 20,
  children: [
    Text('One'),
    Text('Two'),
  ],
)
```

Extension:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension SpacingExtension on Column {
  static Column withSpacing({
    Key? key,
    required List<Widget> children,
    int spacing = 10,
    MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,
    MainAxisSize mainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.max,
    CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    VerticalDirection verticalDirection = VerticalDirection.down,
    TextBaseline? textBaseline,
  }) {
    var spacedChildren = children.expand((widget) => [widget, SizedBox(height: spacing.toDouble())]).toList();
    spacedChildren.removeLast(); // Remove the extra SizedBox

    return Column(
      key: key,
      mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
      mainAxisSize: mainAxisSize,
      crossAxisAlignment: crossAxisAlignment,
      textDirection: textDirection,
      verticalDirection: verticalDirection,
      textBaseline: textBaseline,
      children: spacedChildren,
    );
  }
}
```

---

Or as a widget:

Use:

```
SpacingColumn(
  spacing: 20,
  children: [
    Text('One'),
    Text('Two'),
  ],
)
```

Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SpacingColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  final int spacing;
  final MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment;
  final MainAxisSize mainAxisSize;
  final CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment;
  final TextDirection? textDirection;
  final VerticalDirection verticalDirection;
  final TextBaseline? textBaseline;

  SpacingColumn({
    Key? key,
    required this.children,
    this.spacing = 10,
    this.mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,
    this.mainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.max,
    this.crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    this.textDirection,
    this.verticalDirection = VerticalDirection.down,
    this.textBaseline,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
      mainAxisSize: mainAxisSize,
      crossAxisAlignment: crossAxisAlignment,
      textDirection: textDirection,
      verticalDirection: verticalDirection,
      textBaseline: textBaseline,
      children: children.expand((widget) => [widget, SizedBox(height: spacing.toDouble())]).toList()..removeLast(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an arbitrary long list and wish to insert a `SizedBox` in between each element:

```
Column(
        children: [
      const Text("hello"),
      const Text("hello2"),
      const Text("hello3"),
    ].expand((x) => [const SizedBox(height: 10), x]).skip(1).toList());
  }
```

This inserts a `SizedBox` before every element, then ignores the one inserted before the first one.

Answer (score 0):

use this on every child of the row to give them equal and symmetric space :-

```
Flexible(
     flex: 1,
     fit: FlexFit.tight,
     child: ChildWidget()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic version of what Luke Stanyer suggested is this extension:

```
extension SpacingExtension on Flex {
  Flex withSpacing({
    double spacing = 0.0,
  }) {
    var spacedChildren = this
        .children
        .expand((widget) => [widget, SizedBox.square(dimension: spacing)])
        .toList();

    // Remove the extra SizedBox
    if (spacedChildren.isNotEmpty) spacedChildren.removeLast();

    return Flex(
      direction: this.direction,
      children: spacedChildren,
      crossAxisAlignment: this.crossAxisAlignment,
      mainAxisAlignment: this.mainAxisAlignment,
      mainAxisSize: this.mainAxisSize,
      textDirection: this.textDirection,
      verticalDirection: this.verticalDirection,
      textBaseline: this.textBaseline,
      key: this.key,
    );
  }
}
```

It works for both Columns and Rows.

Answer (score 0):

### If Row is inside your Appbar's Leading Widget (or any constrained in width Widget)

The appbar leading widget is constrained in width, so whatever solution I was trying it would not work.

Fortunately the appbar has the `leadingWidth` property (defaulting to 56), so just increase it as you need.

**As a general rule, try to check if your Row is the child of a widget which has a constrained width.**

```dart
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(leadingWidth: 112, // now the spacing between items in the Row will work!
          leading: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,children:
[...]
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here the another *Custom method* we can use everywhere for both *Horizontal* and *Vertical* Spacing**

> This method for custom **Horizontal spacing**

```
SizedBox horizontalSpace(space) => SizedBox(width: space);
```

> This method for custom **Vertical spacing**

```
SizedBox verticalSpace(space) => SizedBox(height: space);
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget the `.devide(T)` function for a list of widgets. It's my go-to for a constant spacing.

```
Row(
 children:[
    Text('1'),
    Text('2'),
    Text('3'),
  ].divide(SizedBox(
    width: 30,
  ),
),
```