# How to give gaps between FloatingActionButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am just getting started with flutter and not getting how should i give gaps between this 2 FloatingActionButton

```
 Widget abcde = Container(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: (){},
                    child: Icon(Icons.call)),
                FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: (){},
                    child: Icon(Icons.call)),
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Space between Column's children in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774921/space-between-columns-children-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this:

1. Add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,` or another spacing option to the `Row` widget.
2. Wrap your `FloatingActionButtons` with `Container` and add margins/padding, or wrap them with `Padding`/`Margin` widgets directly.
3. Add a widget in between, like a `Container`/`SizedBox`/`Spacer`

I'd recommend 1:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      //Fab 1,
      //Fab 2
    ]
),
```

Comment: Great! Happy to help :D

Answer (score 0):

Add SizedBox.

```
 FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.call)),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.call)),
```

Comment: Mark my answer if is useful.