# Padding not rendering between header and textfield?

Tags: flutter

I want to add space between my header and text field, as currently, they are far too close. I have tried adding padding to the row which has the text field, however, there is no movement. Any thoughts on how I could do so?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
          Image.asset(
            "assets/Login_Photo.jpg",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 35,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                          decoration:
                              InputDecoration(hintText: "Email Address"))),
```

Comment: can produce a minimal, complete, and verifiable example?

Comment: @JohnJoe that is a sample.. works in my enviornment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited your code, So you can wrap `Row` in the `Container` and set margin like as top, bottom ,left, right according to your `UI`, Please tell me if my code is useful or not.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            "assets/Login_Photo.jpg",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 35,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                  child: Row(
                    // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration:
                              InputDecoration(hintText: "Email Address"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SizedBox widget, with the height property, you assign the distance you want to separate. For Exmaple:

```
SizedBox(height: 10)//change this value for which you need.
```

Full code, look like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
          Image.asset(
            "assets/Login_Photo.jpg",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 35,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
                ),
                Sizedbox(height: 10),
                Row(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                          decoration:
                              InputDecoration(hintText: "Email Address"))),
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to work.. throws an error. I tried this as well earlier, the same way you have provided, but no luck. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

How strange that it doesn't work for you, maybe one of these alternatives works for you:

Container and give some height:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Widget1(),
    Container(height: 10), // set height
    Widget2(),
  ],
)
```

Spacer

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Widget1(),
    Spacer(), // use Spacer
    Widget2(),
  ],
)
```

Expanded

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Widget1(),
    Expanded(child: SizedBox()), // use Expanded
    Widget2(),
  ],
)
```

mainAxisAlignment

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, // mainAxisAlignment
  children: <Widget>[
    Widget1(),
    Widget2(),
  ],
)
```

Wrap

```
Wrap(
  direction: Axis.vertical, // make sure to set this
  spacing: 20, // set your spacing
  children: <Widget>[
    Widget1(),
    Widget2(),
  ],
)
```

[Space between Column's children in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774921/space-between-columns-children-in-flutter)